# Solve E2010 Incompatible types: 'AnsiChar' and 'Char'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I try to convert some code from D2007 to XE5 and got

E2010 Incompatible types: 'AnsiChar' and 'Char'

from this code

```
  TSetOfChar = Set of Char;

  var
    CharacterSet: TSetOfChar;
    s: String;

    for j := 1 to Length(s) do
    begin
      Include(CharacterSet, s[j]);  // Error E2010
      if not CaseSensitive then
      begin
        Include(CharacterSet, AnsiUpperCase(s[j])[1]);  // Error E2010
        Include(CharacterSet, AnsiLowerCase(s[j])[1])   // Error E2010
      end
    end;
```

Any suggestion for solution ? I think it is enough to handle AnsiStrings.

Comment: Something similar: I've been having warning on everything like `s[1] in ['A'..'Z','a'..'z','0'..'9']` in recent Delphi versions. Since I don't care about anything outside of the Ansi-range, I do `AnsiChar(s[1]) in [`etc.

Comment: Or use `CharInSet()`, like the compiler warning says.

Comment: @Stijn There are functions that test character properties. No need to shun international text.

Comment: _sigh_ If you're interested, I've vented about this before here: https://plus.google.com/105759934778773466450/posts/LRqD794jd7q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base type for a Delphi set can have at most 256 elements. Which means that your set is in fact really `set of AnsiChar`.

And your code is failing because `AnsiUpperCase(s[j])` is of type `string` which is `UnicodeString`. Hence `AnsiUpperCase(s[j])[1]` is of type `char` which is `WideChar`. Which is what the compiler is trying to tell you. Despite their names, `AnsiUpperCase` and `AnsiLowerCase` operate on, and return `UnicodeString`.

If you really do still want to work with ANSI strings then you will need to use the `AnsiUpperCase` and `AnsiLowerCase` functions from the `AnsiStrings` unit. These versions operate on, and return `AnsiString`. Add that unit to your uses clause, and make sure you pass `AnsiString` values:

```
var
  AnsiStr: AnsiString;
....
AnsiStr := AnsiString(s);
for j := 1 to Length(AnsiStr) do
begin
  Include(CharacterSet, AnsiStr[j]); 
  if not CaseSensitive then
  begin
    Include(CharacterSet, AnsiUpperCase(AnsiStr[j])[1]);  
    Include(CharacterSet, AnsiLowerCase(AnsiStr[j])[1])   
  end
end;
```

Of course, it seems extremely inefficient to be creating strings containing single characters. Surely you can find a way to do this without using heap allocated strings and operating directly on characters.

An obvious improvement would be to call `AnsiUpperCase` once, passing the entire string, and iterate over the upper case string returned. Likewise for `AnsiLowerCase`. Or you could use `CharUpperBuff` and `CharLowerBuff` to avoid heap allocations.

And of course there's the whole issue of Unicode. You are using a Unicode Delphi but being confined to ANSI. Do you really want to do that? If you want to support Unicode then you have to stop using Delphi sets, I am afraid. You'll need a data type that can support sets of wide characters. You would also perhaps need to consider what to do with multi-byte UTF-16 characters.

Comment: Typecasting the string on every loop iteration is inefficient, and potentially dangerous since the loop is still iterating a `UnicodeString` but now indexing into an `AnsiString`.  When a given string is converted between Ansi and Unicode, the lengths of the two versions are not guaranteed to be the same. Best to assign the source `UnicodeString` to a local `AnsiString` variable first, then iterate through the `AnsiString` without typecasts.

Comment: @Remy Yes. I said most of that. But you are right about the lengths. Let me tidy up.

Answer (score 2):

```
  uses
      ..., AnsiStrings;

  type
    TSetOfChar = Set of AnsiChar;

  var
    CharacterSet: TSetOfChar;
    s: AnsiString;

    for j := 1 to Length(s) do
    begin
      Include(CharacterSet, s[j])
      if not CaseSensitive then
      begin
        Include(CharacterSet, AnsiStrings.AnsiUpperCase(s[j])[1]);
        Include(CharacterSet, AnsiStrings.AnsiLowerCase(s[j])[1]);
      end
    end;
```

Alternatively:

```
  uses
      ..., AnsiStrings;

  type
    TSetOfChar = Set of AnsiChar;

  var
    CharacterSet: TSetOfChar;
    s, s2: AnsiString;

    if CaseSensitive then
    begin
      for j := 1 to Length(s) do
        Include(CharacterSet, s[j]);
    end else 
    begin
      s2 := AnsiStrings.AnsiUpperCase(s);
      for j := 1 to Length(s2) do
        Include(CharacterSet, s2[j]);
      s2 := AnsiStrings.AnsiLowerCase(s);
      for j := 1 to Length(s2) do
        Include(CharacterSet, s2[j]);
      end
    end;
```

Comment: Are you going to explain any of this, or are the explanations in my answer sufficient?