# Delphi 2010 Error E2010 Incompatible types: Char' and 'AnsiChar'

Tags: delphi

I loaded up some code from Delphi and when I compile it inside Delphi 2010 I get an E2010 Incompatible types:  'Char' and 'AnsiChar'.

How do I resolve this error? help please

```
function TFKirimEmail.ChAnsiToWide(const StrA: AnsiString): WideString;
var
  nLen: integer;
begin
  Result := StrA;
  if Result <> '' then
  begin
    nLen := MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 1, PChar(@StrA[1]), -1, nil, 0);
    SetLength(Result, nLen - 1);
    if nLen > 1 then
      MultiByteToWideChar(GetACP(), 1, PChar(@StrA[1]), -1, PWideChar(@Result[1]), nLen - 1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solve E2010 Incompatible types: 'AnsiChar' and 'Char'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593501/solve-e2010-incompatible-types-ansichar-and-char)

Comment: I'm assuming the code which you "loaded up" was from a version of Delphi earlier than 2010. You should be aware that as of D2010, Unicode is strictly enforced, which means `PChar`, rather than pointing to `PAnsiChar` it now points to `PWideChar`. So presumably, your cases of `PChar` should be cast as `PAnsiChar`.

Comment: You resolve the error by deleting the function because it's not needed at all in your Unicode Delphi. Do you know what Unicode is? Do you know about `UnicodeString`, and the fact that `string` is now an alias to `UnicodeString`? If you know nothing at all about Unicode then you should not be asking this question. Read Marco's whitepaper and then you'll be ready to proceed.

Comment: @David Good catch, I didn't even pay attention to what the function actually does, just the fact that it uses `PChar`.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Delphi made the switch to Unicode in D2009, not D2010.

Comment: You should also ask yourself why you have an instance method of a class named TFKirimEmail that performs string conversions and does not use any instance variables. In other words this code is not a good starting place.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for that, I forgot there was even a Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi 2009 and later, `(P)Char` is an alias for `(P)WideChar`, whereas it was an alias for `(P)AnsiChar` in earlier versions.  That is why you are getting a compiler error.

The third parameter of `MultiByteToWideChar()` expects a `PAnsiChar` in all versions of Delphi.  So simply change `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`.  Which will work fine considering that `StrA` is `AnsiString` and not `String` (which is an alias for `UnicodeString` in D2009+), so they will match.

That being said, you should be using the `CP_ACP` constant instead of the `GetACP()` function, remove the redundant assignment (and conversion) to `Result` before calling `MultiByteToWideChar()`, remove unnecessary character indexing, and remove unnecessary null terminator handling:

```
function TFKirimEmail.ChAnsiToWide(const StrA: AnsiString): WideString;
var
  nLen: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  nLen := MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, PAnsiChar(StrA), Length(StrA), nil, 0);
  if nLen > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, nLen);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, PAnsiChar(StrA), Length(StrA), PWideChar(Result), nLen);
  end;
end;
```

With that said, don't use `WideString` in D2009+ for non-ActiveX work.  `UnicodeString` is more efficient.

```
function TFKirimEmail.ChAnsiToWide(const StrA: AnsiString): UnicodeString;
```

Lastly, since you are setting the `CodePage` to ACP and the `dwFlags` parameter to `MB_PRECOMPOSED` (which is the default if no other flags are specified), you could just eliminate all this code and let the RTL handle the conversion for you, since it uses those same settings internally by default:

```
function TFKirimEmail.ChAnsiToWide(const StrA: AnsiString): WideString;
begin
  Result := WideString(StrA);
end;
```

Or:

```
function TFKirimEmail.ChAnsiToWide(const StrA: RawByteString): UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := UnicodeString(StrA);
end;
```

In which case, your `ChAnsiToWide()` function becomes redundant and can be eliminated completely.